# How to update an Android widget every second ... to draw a clock with a seconds hand?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have been reading much from various sources on ways to update a widget that is using ImageView Canvas and Draw method to display a clock with a seconds hand.

It must be updated every second. What is the most efficient way to do this? Use a `Service`, the Alarm Manager, Handlers?

It can be done, e.g., the Android app ["Arc Clock Widget"](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/arc-clock-widget_jimn.html).

Anyone with any ideas?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Updating a homescreen widget every second will be a serious battery drain

Comment: I have read this from other sources as well.  I must ask a maybe obvious question... WHY?  My phone simply goes to sleep after a minute or so and ANYTHING running on it does not matter... it still goes to sleep.  It seems that the phone takes care of itself when it comes to battery life, regardless of what is running.  Why would an app, updating a clock every second cause the battery to be drained?  Thanks, Tom

Comment: Well, the widget update mechanism really does wake up a sleeping device at each update - this is why the minimum interval allowed for widgets is 30 minutes and it's bad to have something done every second. BUT: Tom is not wrong either! Scheduling an alarm as mentioned in the Android Development Guide that does not wake the device (using AlarmManager) should be fine! As long as the device is awake it does not matter what you do! If it's asleep, nothing happens. I got the same problem and I am tired of answers stating it's bad to update a widget frequently!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions discussed on this page :) [A Tutorial on Making an Analog Clock Widget for Android](http://aedus.com/blog/2011/05/29/how-to-create-an-analog-clock-widget-for-android/)

I have used the AlarmManager to do this myself and I did not notice any significant battery drain as the AlarmManager does not wake the phone to update the widget when the phone is asleep. Anyways, no one will be seeing the widget when the phone is asleep. Also, see this note on this section of the Android Developer Guide. [Using AlarmManager to update frequently](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData)