# Draw every 1 second

Tags: java, android

i am trying to create android app , with clock that contain Second hand , the hand is moving every second , the code that i write just crash after few seconds , and doesn't work as well .. any ideas ?

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

class Circles extends View
{

public Circles(Context context)
  {
      super(context);    
  }

  protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) 
  {
      super.onDraw(canvas);
      //2 Circels
      Paint p1 = new Paint();
      p1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      p1.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
       Paint p2 = new Paint();
      p2.setColor(Color.RED);
      p2.setStyle(Style.FILL);
      canvas.drawCircle(500, 250, 250, p1);
      canvas.drawCircle(500, 250, 20, p2);
      invalidate();

      // Seconds
      final Paint p3 = new Paint();
      p3.setColor(Color.RED);
      p3.setStyle(Style.FILL);

  Runnable seconds = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            canvas.drawLine(500, 250 , 500 , 400, p3 );
        }
    }; 
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(seconds, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
  }


}
```

Comment: What do the errors look like (logcat). Do you know for sure it's coming from here?

Comment: Just a warning, I believe that any solution you find to this may significantly effect your battery life, as would any timed UI updates

Comment: if i can suggest something, dont create your executor in onDraw method, because each time when it is caled, you will have new instance with new task running

Comment: Handlers is the best way to manage periodic tasks in Android. Check out this article http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486243/how-to-update-an-android-widget-every-second-to-draw-a-clock-with-a-seconds?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

If you want to redraw every second, don't write a timer that executes draw code. It's a bad idea to call onDraw explicitly.

Instead write a timer that invalidates the canvas every second. If you invalidate the canvas it will automatically be repainted by the code you already have. Using the Runnable approach you are currently using that could be:

```
Runnable seconds = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myView.postInvalidate();
    }
};
```

However Handlers are probably a better way to schedule periodic tasks.

Make sure your draw code finds the correct time to draw.

You also don't want to call canvas.invalidate() from within onDraw. That will cause the view to redraw again as soon as it has finished drawing. That's what is causing the crash. Even if you wanted continuous draw, postInvalidate(0 is a better method to call.

Comment: canvas.postInvalidate(); brings for me an error "The method postInvalidate() is undefined for the type Canvas" ......

Comment: My mistake. postInvalidate() should be called on the View.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to use Java's [timer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

int interval = 1000; // One second

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
       place your code here that you'd like to run every second
  }
}, timeinterval);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem that OP is having.

Answer (score 1):

I think that app crashes becouse your method  canvas.drawLine invoke recursive onDraw. Just try to move your executor from onDraw.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend Android's Thread class:

```
public class ClockThread extends Thread {
    private boolean running = false;
    private Circles circles;
    private long lastUpdate;

   public ClockThread (Circles circles) {
        this.circles = circles;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {

            // Compare current time to last time it was drawn
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate > 1000) {

                // Create draw method in Circles to update properly
                circles.draw();
                lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can create a new Thread once you create the Circles object:

```
ClockThread clockThread = new ClockThread(circles);
```

And when you want to start it:

```
clockThread.setRunning(true);
clockThread.start();
```

Comment: This is overkill, and doesn't fix the problem, and calls the system clock in a continuous loop.